# Data Parallel Primitives Library for OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am trying to implement a Minimum Spanning Forest Algorithm in OpenCL. Though I know how to implement Kruskal's algorithm, it is sequential in nature, so I think Boruvka's algorithm or the Data Parallel Kruskal's algorithm which is specially made for parallel programming should be implemented in OpenCL.
   But in this algorithm(as per mentioned in the paper : "Fast and Memory-Efficient Minimum Spanning Tree on the GPU") we need Graph Primitives like "sort", "split graph", "connect components", "find mins", "contract graphs" for the implementation. Does OpenCL have its Data Parallel Primitives library as the CUDA does...." CUDAPP"..? Or is there any source in OpenCL where I can get these functions...?

Comment: OpenCL is a standard whereas CUDA is a product, there are no official "OpenCL" libraries, but implementors may provide some (for instance AMD provides some generic libraries for OpenCL, e.g. I know it has a CUBLAS equivalent). Don't know if there's anything quite like CUDAPP though.

Comment: ArrayFire (which is a project I work on) has data parallel primitives for OpenCL, currently in pre-release form. Will be available in v2.0 very soon. http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire